# Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkNotNullParameter, parameter settings

Tags: java, module, expo, native

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkNotNullParameter, parameter settings
    at expo.modules.facedetector.ExpoFaceDetector.setSettings(Unknown Source:2)
    at expo.modules.camera.ExpoCameraView.onHostResume(ExpoCameraView.kt:216)
    at expo.modules.adapters.react.services.UIManagerModuleWrapper$3.onHostResume(UIManagerModuleWrapper.java:127)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContext.onHostResume(ReactContext.java:240)
    at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.moveToResumedLifecycleState(ReactInstanceManager.java:719)
    at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.onHostResume(ReactInstanceManager.java:623)
    at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.onHostResume(ReactInstanceManager.java:580)
    at com.facebook.react.ReactDelegate.onHostResume(ReactDelegate.java:53)
    at com.facebook.react.ReactActivityDelegate.onResume(ReactActivityDelegate.java:100)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at expo.modules.ReactActivityDelegateWrapper.invokeDelegateMethod(ReactActivityDelegateWrapper.kt:166)
    at expo.modules.ReactActivityDelegateWrapper.onResume(ReactActivityDelegateWrapper.kt:82)
    at com.facebook.react.ReactActivity.onResume(ReactActivity.java:58)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1462)
    at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:8129)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4428)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4470)
    at android.app.servertransaction.ResumeActivityItem.execute(ResumeActivityItem.java:52)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:176)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7664)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

whenever a parameter is not nullable just add "?" -nullable operator to it, for instance;

```
  fun doSomething(parameter: Parameter?){
     //Voila, issue solved
  }
```

Clarification;

Apparently you're working in a project utilizing both languages Java and Kotlin. This error appears when Kotlin runs a Java-based function that might provide a null valued parameter, and Kotlin as a null-safe programming language can't detect this from Java in Compile time!

so once a case happens with a null valued parameter on runtime it will through this Crash